# Cannot Access Google Colab when logged in with Google Workplace Account

Tags: google-colaboratory

We are having an issue that is causing a lot of tickets to roll in for us. We have professors that have been using Google Colaboratory with their students and we are getting reports that students are not able to access Colaboratory via their University Google Accounts for at least the last week, if not longer. They are receiving error messages that state "you don't have access to this service" and asks them to contact their Google Account Administrator for access. If they log out and log in with a personal gmail account they are able to access it. I have had multiple calls in with Google Support now and they are telling me that because Google Colaboratory is not a Workplace application, they are very limited as to what they can do and they have yet to find a solution to the problem.

The only information that I’ve been able to find online is the Colaboratory Team asking users to toggle a setting in Google Workplace (https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1065#issuecomment-605486998)  however that setting is already toggled on for our account so it is of no help.

Also, I will note that the issue only seems to be happening for our students who are a part of our root organizational unit while Faculty and Staff appear to have access to Colab and they are in a sub group of the OU.

Could someone help?